# How to update the SKU's of ordered products in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have to update the product sku to new sku so that was done easily, but after that only realized i should update the ordered product sku's too.

How can i update the ordered product sku in magento. Please help me.

I tried this one

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadBySku("sku");
```

But this returns fatal error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Varien_Exception' with message
>   'Invalid method
>   Mage_Sales_Model_Order::loadBySku(Array
>   ( [0] => koboonyx ) )' in
>   /home/makegood/public_html/mage34/lib/Varien/Object.php:567 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/makegood/public_html/mage34/sku.php(7):
>   Varien_Object->__call('loadBySku',
>   Array) #1
>   /home/makegood/public_html/mage34/sku.php(7):
>   Mage_Sales_Model_Order->loadBySku('koboonyx')
>   2 {main} thrown in /home/makegood/public_html/mage34/lib/Varien/Object.php
>   on line 567

Or do i have to load orders by order id and then should update the ***sku to new sku***

Like this

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
{

}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you mean to do this:

```
$orderItems = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $oldSKU);
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
    $item->setSku($newSKU)
        ->save();
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a few seconds :)

Comment: At last my obsessive visiting/surfing pays off!!